# Lost USB BlueTooth Dongle for Mouse

Tags: usb, mouse, dongle

I lost my USB bluetooth dongle (from DEll) which I used for a wireless  mouse. kindly provide solution

Comment: Solution: Either find it back or buy a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If it's actually Bluetooth, you can use any Bluetooth old adapter.

If, and I suspect this is the case, it's RF, there isn't a lot you can do as there are no generic replacements for this. You might have some luck with the manufacturer, but honestly, you're probably best off looking for a replacement for the set.